# Windows Server (IIS) + PHP7.4 - problem with curl

Tags: php, curl, iis

I have a strange problem with curl - one version doesn't work with CLI, but works with the web, the other one doesn't work with web, but works with CLI.

I have two DLL files: `php_curl.dll` (v7.4.1 - works with CLI) and `php_curl_2.dll` (v7.3.1 - works with web). I don't have a separate `php.ini` for the CLI.

With v7.3.1 loaded CLI can't find the module, although it looks for the correct path:

```
extension=php_curl2.dll
```

gives

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_curl2.dll' (tried: C:...\php_curl2.dll (Can't find given module.), C:...\php_php_curl2.dll.dll (Can't find given module.)) in Unknown on line 0

The first path is correct, the second one adds prefix & suffix, so I tried `extension=curl2`, but with a similar result (just the first path is incorrect and the second one correct).

With v7.4.1 situation is analogous, but the other way round: can't load module for the web, but for the CLI is OK.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Since upgrading to PHP 7.4.23 (from 7.0.7). My CURL scripts run fine in the CLI, but just throw 500 errors through a browser. Luckily they are batch scripts but I used to be able to run them manually through the browser. Now I have to login to the machine and use the CLI. It looks like you are trying to solve the same problem. Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: @AngusWalker Yes, actually the solution was trivial and the question above isn't relevant - I had bad dll version.

Comment: So once you resolved the dll issue you used the 7.4 dll for the CLI and the 7.3 for the web? Or are you saying you just had a corrupt 7.4 dll and now it works for both?

Comment: @AngusWalker To be honest I can't remember exactly, and won't be able to check as I changed job ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could follow the below steps to configure Curl installation on Windows IIS:

Edit your php.ini and uncomment/add the line:

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

Please make sure php_curl.dll exists in the C:\php\ext folder. If you are using the PHP installer, this component seems not to be selected by the installer by default.

And check for correct extension dir:

```
extension_dir = "c:/path to php/ext"
```

**Uncomment** extension=php_curl.dll. You can do this by removing ; in front of line.

Check that php_curl.dll exists in extension_dir . If it does not exist - download Win32 zip package of the corresponding PHP version from https://www.php.net/downloads.php.

Go to the PHP directory and copy the following libraries to the windows/system32 dir.

> ssleay32.dll
>
> libeay32.dll

If there are no such files in PHP directory and its sub-directories, you need to run PHP installation and add Curl extension.

And another step - check if allow_url_fopen option is enabled. It is set in php.ini file as well.

Restart iis server after doing changes.

If this doesn't help and you still do not see Curl enabled, restart the physical machine. You might especially need it if you have run PHP installation recently.

you can verify if curl is loaded by PHP using phpinfo().

Create phpinfo.php file and type this code below as content.

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

This document should be placed inside the C:\inetpub\wwwroot folder.

Run Internet Explorer, and type http://localhost/phpinfo.php in address bar.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it doesn't solve my problem.